# gSoap: HTTP Header, Content-Length: 0

Tags: c++, soap, salesforce, gsoap

I am attempting to use gSoap in a c++ client to access the salesforce.com API using the below code:

```
struct soap soap;

soap_init(&soap);

_ns1__login loginReq;
_ns1__loginResponse loginRes;

loginReq.username = "XXXX";
loginReq.password = "XXXX";

if(soap_call___ns1__login(&soap,NULL,NULL,&loginReq,&loginRes) == 0){
    qDebug() << loginRes.result->sessionId;
} else {
    soap_print_fault(&soap, stderr);
    soap_print_fault_location(&soap, stderr);
}
```

This complies without a problem but when run produces the following error:

```
SOAP 1.1 fault: SOAP-ENV:Client [no subcode]
"Validation constraint violation: tag name or namespace mismatch in element <soapenv:Envelope>"
Detail: [no detail]
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: 
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 625
Date: Fri, 29 Apr 2011 00:56:17 GMT
Connection: close

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sf="urn:fault.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION</faultcode><faultstring>UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Premature end of file.</faultstring><detail><sf:UnexpectedErrorFault xsi:type="sf:UnexpectedErrorFault"><sf:exceptionCode>UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION</sf:exceptionCode><sf:exceptionMessage>Premature end of file.</sf:exceptionMessage></sf:UnexpectedErrorFault></detail></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
<!-- ** HERE ** -->
```

I have run a packet capture and everything looks correct except for the 'Content-Length' in the HTTP header shows 0:

```
POST /services/Soap/c/21.0 HTTP/1.1
Host: login.salesforce.com
User-Agent: gSOAP/2.7
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
SOAPAction: ""

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns2="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:ns3="urn:fault.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:ns1="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com"><SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><ns1:login><ns1:username>XXXX</ns1:username><ns1:password>XXXX</ns1:password></ns1:login></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

If anyone has any insights into where I am going wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

I am using gSoap 2.7 on Debian 6.0 using g++ 4.4.5 to compile if that is any help.

Comment: I might sound weird, but I am trying to find a clue to work with VC++, gSOAP and salesforce.com. Would you like to show me some documents, if you don't mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very old question, but I had the same issue recently. The issue for me was that I was mixing c++ code and c code. I'd compiled stdsoap2.c rather than stdsoap2.cpp and for some reason this prevented the correct count being made for content-length. Once I created the correct object and re-linked to it, the solution worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

From the packet capture you have provided, there is another key point to observe. The SOAPAction field is empty.

Here is a sample packet capture of my app:

```
POST /ws/smi/v1/IndexService HTTP/1.1
Host: somevalidwebservice.com
User-Agent: gSOAP/2.8
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1180
Connection: close
SOAPAction: "http://www.somevalidwebservice.com/ws/smi/v1/getIndex"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:ns1="http://www.somevalidwebservice.com/ws/smi/v1"
<SOAP-ENV:Header></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><nsGlobal:getIndexRequest></nsGlobal:getIndexRequest>
```

Can you check if you are specifying the SOAP Action paramter correctly?

Comment: SOAPAction can be empty; See http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383528

Comment: I copied my packet capture, altered the content-length by hand and sent it to the server using socat. This returned the expected response back so I think it is safe to presume that the problem only relates to the content-length header filed.